Nested transaction support for mysql with spring transactional
I've a stored procedure in MySQL which is being executed in @Transactional method.
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeSalary (IN newSalary DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
    UPDATE Employee
    SET Salary = newSalary
    WHERE EmployeeID = 1;
END //
DELIMITER ;

Now since @Transactional starts its own transaction and the SP doest have any, it gets rolled back if there's any error in the callee method or transaction, which is as expected.
However my concern comes from what if someone executes the SP from console and an error is thrown from the SP.
Example
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeSalary (IN newSalary DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
    UPDATE Employee
    SET Salary = newSalary
    WHERE EmployeeID = 1;

    -- simulate error
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Failed to update employee salary';

END //
DELIMITER ;

In this case since mysql is in auto commit mode, it'll commit the salary update and then throw the error. However to not let that happen, if I add transaction inside the SP i.e.
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployeeSalary (IN newSalary DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE Employee
    SET Salary = newSalary
    WHERE EmployeeID = 1;
COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;

it then doesn't get rollback with spring @Transactional if there's error in the callee method since mysql doesnt support nested transaction (it gets committed on COMMIT)
I'm not sure what is the correct way to solve this problem
Currently ive removed the transaction from SP and let spring manage the transaction which works well but will go into inconsistent state when someone runs the SP via console (non transaction way) and it throws error post UPDATE call.
